# AEM | xtype | multifield+tags

Tags: aem

There seems to be some problem while trying to persist values using combination of `multifield` and `tags`. When I use these widgets data gets saved properly and visible in page properties but while trying to read the data (by reopening the editor dialog) it shows error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly add a screenshot of the page where data gets stored.

Comment: I think, you are not supposed to use `name: ./tags` in `fieldConfig` node. One multi-field is proportional to one property of a component. Please clarify the intent of your work.